# How to query MarkLogic on a specific uri?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using `Marklogic8`, and based on a business rule, I write JSON to two different URIs, **uriA** and **uriB**.
 
The use case is the files can contain same elements and same values eg: a `timestamp`.
 
When I search based on the timestamp, I need files from only one URI say **uriB**. 
How do I get that?

Comment: Can you show the code you are currently using to search `timestamp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the URI ahead of time, then you can simply AND your query with a `cts:document-query`:

```
cts:and-query((
  cts:json-property-query('timestamp', $myTimestamp), (: Or however you query timestamps :)
  cts:document-query('uriB')
))
```

**Update:**

Using Java API you could build a similar query:

```
StructuredQueryBuilder sb = ...
StructuredQueryDefinition sq =
  sb.and(
    sb.document("uriB"), 
    sb.containerQuery(sb.jsonProperty("timestamp"), myTimestamp));
```

Comment: Thanks @wst, Is there a way I can do this via `JSON QUERY` via `JAVA API` ?

Comment: @VikramR The answer has been updated with a Java API example.